# Method that turns image to BW does not work

Tags: c#, bitmap, gdi+, unsafe, bitmapdata

```
public float ToBlackAndWhite(BlackWhiteMode mode)
    {
        var data = _bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, _bmp.PixelFormat);

        var IsWhite = mode switch
        {
            BlackWhiteMode.Brightness => new Predicate<Color>(x => x.GetBrightness() > 0.5),
            BlackWhiteMode.Hue => new Predicate<Color>(x => x.GetHue() > 180),
            _ => new Predicate<Color>(x => x.GetSaturation() > 0.5)
        };
        
        int sum = 0;
        unsafe
        {
            var pixelSize = Image.GetPixelFormatSize(_bmp.PixelFormat) / 8;

            var ptr = (byte*)data.Scan0;

            byte* row;
            byte* pixel;
            for (int y = 0; y < data.Height; y++)
            {
                row = ptr + y * data.Stride;

                for (int x = 0; x < data.Width; x++)
                {
                    pixel = row + x * pixelSize;

                    if (IsWhite(new(pixel[2], pixel[1], pixel[0])))
                    {
                        pixel[2] = MAX;
                        pixel[1] = MAX;
                        pixel[0] = MAX;
                        sum--;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        pixel[2] = MIN;
                        pixel[1] = MIN;
                        pixel[0] = MIN;
                        sum++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        _bmp.UnlockBits(data);

        return (float)Math.Abs(sum) / PixelCount;
    }
```

This method locks a System.Drawing.Bitmap and replaces all pixels with black or white pixels based of the IsWhite Predicate (Pixel nearer to black = black, nearer to white = white). But every image I tried only returns a full white or full black image. Why does that happen?

I also have this method that replaces transparent pixels with full visible pixels that uses the same method and it works fine.

```
public void InvertTransparency()
    {
        var data = _bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, _bmp.PixelFormat);

        unsafe
        {
            var pixelSize = Image.GetPixelFormatSize(_bmp.PixelFormat) / 8;

            var ptr = (byte*)data.Scan0;

            byte* row;
            byte* pixel;

            ulong r = 0;
            ulong g = 0;
            ulong b = 0;
            for (int y = 0; y < data.Height; y++)
            {
                row = ptr + y * data.Stride;

                for (int x = 0; x < data.Width; x++)
                {
                    pixel = row + x * pixelSize;

                    r += pixel[2];
                    g += pixel[1];
                    b += pixel[0];
                }
            }

            var invertedAvg = new Color(
                MAX - (r / (ulong)PixelCount),
                MAX - (g / (ulong)PixelCount),
                MAX - (b / (ulong)PixelCount));


            for (int y = 0; y < data.Height; y++)
            {
                row = ptr + y * data.Stride;

                for (int x = 0; x < data.Width; x++)
                {
                    pixel = row + x * pixelSize;

                    if (pixel[3] < 128)
                    {
                        pixel[3] = MAX;
                        pixel[2] = invertedAvg.R;
                        pixel[1] = invertedAvg.G;
                        pixel[0] = invertedAvg.B;
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (pixel[3] != MAX)
                        pixel[3] = MAX;
                }
            }
        }

        _bmp.UnlockBits(data);
    }
```

Thank you for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

The way you check for a color to be white is wrong, these `Color` methods are based on the HSL color space:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color.gethue?view=net-7.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color.getsaturation?view=net-7.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color.getbrightness?view=net-7.0

The only thing you need to do is `.GetBrightness() >= 1.0f`:

[image]

https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_hsl.asp

Comment: I want to check if a color is nearer to white or to black and not if it is white.

Comment: The goal is to replace the pixel with black and white based on if they are nearer to black or white.
Nearer to black => black,
Nearer to white => white

Comment: You could use Euclidean distance or anything else more involved (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference). If you solely want to use `Color` methods, you could do `x => x.GetSaturation() <= 0.1f && x.GetBrightness() >= 0.9f` and adjust accordingly. It all really depends on how exact you want the results to be, i.e. the HSL color space isn't perfect but that might sufficient for your needs.